# How to solve the following optimization problem with two constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, problem-solving

$G(x,y)$= $\max   (xk_1+(1-x)\log_2(1+\frac{xyk_2}{1-x}))$,

subject to: $0 \le x \le 1 $, $0 \le y \le 1$,

where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are two positive quantity. Individually  it is observed that $G(x,y)$ is a concave function of $x$ when $y$ is kept constant and also it is a concave function of $y$ when $x$ is considered as constant. What will happen when both the constraints are there?

Comment: Please edit the question to specify whether you want to maximize or minimize $G$ with respect to those constraints

Comment: yes ... done that

Comment: @madnessweasley now it is fine?

Comment: @River Li can you please help with this problem?